# Azure AD Exception: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler<TOptions>.HandleRequestAsync()

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I try add Azure AD auth. I alredy have a default auth with `AccountController`

When I try call https://localhost:44304/signin-oidc I get error

[image]

I try connect like:

```
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration);
```

or

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
 .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

AzureAd implemented in appsettings, for test project it works.

```
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I try call https://localhost:44304/signin-oidc I get error

**When you call above url by broswer directly, it should be Http GET request. This is the reason you are experiencing the phenomenon.**

**Step 1**

*Open F12 to monitor the Http request in the Network.*

[image]

*1. Under normal operation steps, the captured Http Request is of the post method.*

[image]

2. call `https://localhost:44304/signin-oidc` by browser.

[image]

## Related issue

[Microsoft Account Authentication not working
#1012](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1012)

> CallbackPath is used for the middleware to receive the results of the remote auth. You do not need a route/controller/action for this path. Once it has processed the results and generated the sign-in identity/cookie, then it will redirect back to your app code, either to where it started or where you told it to return to in the initial challenge.

> Recommendation: keep the default CallbackPath value /signin-microsoft and register https://localhost:50001/signin-microsoft in the MSA portal.

Comment: I need to redirect to signin-in by button click.
Could you share how I can bind signin link to button in project?

Comment: @Chmelya Check the _loginPartial.cshtml, when click the button, you just need to invoke ‘Account/Login‘.

Comment: I am still a bit confused. I am not using `Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI` and using my own `account` controller with `signin` action just like the old plain MSAL days. From `_loginPartial` signin link (which is just a link to this signin action), it gives me this same error.